# SIGINT ignored in google pubsub_v1/python

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

def run():
  # created full_* vars here...

  future = subscriber.subscribe(full_subscription, print_and_ack_message)

  try:
    future.result()
  except KeyboardInterrupt: # this doesn't work for some reason...
    logging.info("Subscription terminated...")
    future.cancel()
  except BaseException as exc:
    logging.info("Other %s", type(exc))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

The above code cannot be interrupted on macOS, zsh, iTerm and pyenv-virtualenv with python 2.7.15, for some reason?

CTRL+C fails from the terminal with this code; nothing happens, only `^C` is visible in the output and it does neither terminate nor print anything. What is wrong?

I'm following the [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#subscription-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `result` method here:

> The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.

```
def run():
    future = subscriber.subscribe(full_subscription, print_and_ack_message)
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        future.cancel()
```